# Deciphering old handwriting from a 1850 church record

Tags: translation, german-to-english, handwriting

Is there anyone that can please decipher the following old german handwriting?  It's from an old Silesian church record written in 1850.  Any help with this is very much appreciated!

[image]

Comment: To closevoter: this question is not off-topic! https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/579/are-questions-on-reading-of-old-handwritings-on-topic

Answer (score 8):

Here's an attempt to transcription. A translation would bo off-topic, though:

> Schwandorf den 22:ten Juni [1850]
>   Wurde von dem Pfarrer Hoffmann getraut der Dienstknecht Anton Weidlith
>   zu Schwandorf, jüngster Sohn des in Wintau verstorbenen  Einwohners
>   Johann Weidlith, mit Thecla Hoffmann, ältester Tochter des in
>   Schwandorf verstorbenen Häuslers Johann Hoffmann.
>   Zeugen Franz
>   Hauorie (?) Häusler in Warben
>   Theresia Langer Gärtnerfrau in
>   Schwandorf.
>   Vermerk. da
>    die Thecla Hoffmann während ihres ledigen
>   Standes zwei Knaben geboren, Joseph, geb. zu Schwandorf am 28. Juli
>   1847, und Anton, geb. zu Schwandorf am 4. Januar 1850, so wurde der p.
>   Weidlith gefragt, ob er der naturliche Vater und Erzeuger dieser
>   Kinder sei. Derselbe erklärte sich bejahend; er sei der Vater der
>   genannten Kinder, die darüber unter dem 21. Juni a.c. aufgenommene
>   Verhandlung ist unter dem 23. Juni a.c. an das Königliche KreisGerichts zu Naila engereicht worden
>   Das Pfarr. Amt

Comment: _"A translation would bo off-topic"_ No worries, deciphering handwriting would be fine regardless of plain translation questions IIRC.

Comment: Just guessing: "Weidlch", "Winsau", "Thecla", "Häusler", "Hauche", "Gärtnerfrau".

Comment: @Uwe thanks for "Thecla" :)

Comment: "Häusler" might be worth a translation: "Small peasant owning a house and no or next to no own fields"

Comment: @tofro, thanks! Removed the questionmaks :)

Comment: "geborene Joseph" > "geboren: Joseph" (mit Doppelpunkt)

Comment: Of course, @fdb  "geboren" it is. Thanks. At this time ist was not uncommon in the "Kanzleisprache" to write the perfect tense with an omitted auxiliary verb ("hat")

Comment: Last sentence : the regional court for Schwandorf used to be in *Naila*.